# How can I append the text in text box?

Tags: jquery

```
$("#textbox1").innerHTML=d.PhoneNo;
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/nagabhavani/4nLge5se/2/)

When I'm doing this all the numbers which are in d[i]. PhoneNo is appending to only one text box.. But I am trying to append the phone numbers to number of text boxes if there are more phone numbers than one.

I am aiming for the output

123456 in textbox1
1234567 in textbox2

from d.PhoneNo

Comment: what is the format of data in `d.PhoneNo` - is it an array for space separated list of numbers

Comment: also it should be `$("#textbox1").val(d.PhoneNo);`

Comment: $("#textbox1").val(d.PhoneNo) this way to assign value

Comment: Yes ..PhoneNo is an array  @ArunPJohny

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see how to ask a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$.each(d.PhoneNo,function(i,num) {
  $("#textbox"+(i+1)).val(num);
});
```

UPDATE:

I changed the phone number ID to textbox10

The next one will be textbox11 if there are more than one phone number

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/9gccfw73/)

```
$.each(item.PhoneNo, function (i, num) {
  if(i>0) $("<input type='text' class='append' id='textbox1"+i+"' name='number'>")
             .insertAfter("#textbox1" + (i-1));
  $("#textbox1" + i).val(num);
});
```

Comment: @NagaBhavani Great. I updated the fiddle to handle email too

Answer (score 0):

Since you have an array, you can iterate over it and assign each value to a text field like

```
$.each(d.PhoneNo, function (i, no) {
    $("#textbox" + (i + 1)).val(no);
})
```

Comment: Drat. Busy editing his question and telling him about help got me in as second on identical solutions...

Comment: @mplungjan that happens... :)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nagabhavani/4nLge5se/2/

Once analyse the code in the above fiddle and please try to give me a solution.The phone input field is displayed empty.

Thank you in Advance

Comment: @ArunPJohny I am not sure if your fiddle solution is elegant or hard to grasp - especially for noobs ;)

Comment: @mplungjan may be... little crazy logic